# Proving boolean algebra

Tags: proof-verification, boolean-algebra

Apologies for the unspecific title.

Correct me if I have not understood this correctly, which is why I've posted this question:

$B$ is a Boolean algebra. Prove for $x, y \in B$ that $x \cdot y' = 0$ if and only if $x \cdot y = x$

Can this be proven with identity law? For $x \cdot y = x$ to be true, $y$ needs to be $1$ (considering identity law). That makes $x \cdot y' = 0$.

Is this valid proof?

Comment: No, it's not.  Note that $x \cdot y = x$ is also satisfied by $y=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the identity law: it says that if $y=1$ then $x\cdot y=x$, but it doesn't say the converse, which is what you're using.

I recommend thinking about some [specific Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Concrete_Boolean_algebras) and playing around the operations, to get a sense of what they're acting like. You'll quickly stumble across nontrivial examples where $x\cdot y=x$ but $y\ne1$.

As for your actual question: consider $x\cdot(y+y')$....